# TypeError: events.replace is not a function JqueryWebcam Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-webcam-plugin

[image]For some strange reason i began to get this error **`TypeError: events.replace is not a function`**. I am using Jquery Webcam Plugin i was able to see the flash player camera moments ago until i did a recompile of the code and got this error. Under is my imported scripts:

**Scripts**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/jQuery-webcam/jquery.webcam.js"></script>
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/citizen_registration.js"></script>


    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/forms.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/citizen_registration.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i updated the jquery plugin to `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`